# How can I auto logout vue app after tab is closed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to logout my vue app after closing the tab of my app and clear all the credentials, and again when someone types the address I want a login page again

Comment: What did you tried so far ? Also, It totally based on the implementation you have on login. I mean how you are storing the login info ? Via store, cookies, localStorage or sessionStorage

Comment: Save credentials in sessionStorage.

Comment: I am using localStorage

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this way

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    window.localStorage.clear();
});
```

Or more affective for Vue Js use

```
<script>
  export default {
    created() {

      window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
        // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
        event.preventDefault();
        // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
        event.returnValue = '';
      });

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: should I put this code in App.vue???

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes